# Some lines of code is not executing

Tags: r

This is my code of R
I want to find our permutation and combination in  a switch case format
The code is not showing aby syntactical errors
but

```
perm <- Fact(n) / Fact(n-r)
sprintf("P(n,r): %.10f", perm)
```

similarly

```
comb <- Fact(t) / (Fact(k)*Fact(t-k))
sprintf("C(n,r): %.10f", comb)
```

these statements in both the functions are not executing:

```
ProbAnl <- function()
{
#menu
print("Select choice: ")
print("1. Permutation")
print("2. Combination")

choice = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter choice: "))

#switch case for menu
result <- switch(choice, Perm(), Comb())
}

Fact = function(num)
{
factorial <- 1  
for(i in 1:num) 
{
    temp = factorial * i
    factorial <- temp
    }
return(factorial)
}

Perm = function()
{
cat("Enter the required parameters: \n")

n <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Set size(n): "))
r <- as.integer(readline(prompt="No. of objects chosen from the set(r): "))

perm <- Fact(n) / Fact(n-r)
sprintf("P(n,r): %.10f", perm)  

repeat
{
    ans <- readline(prompt="Do you want to go back to the Probability 
                   Analysis Menu ?(y/n)\n")

    if(ans == 'y' | ans == 'n')
        break
    else
        cat("Wrong Input. Enter again.\n")

}

if(ans == 'y')
    ProbAnl()
else
    Perm()
}

Comb = function()
{
cat("Enter the required parameters: \n")

t <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Set size(n): "))
k <- as.integer(readline(prompt="No. of objects chosen from the set(r): "))

comb <- Fact(t) / (Fact(k)*Fact(t-k))
sprintf("C(n,r): %.10f", comb)

    repeat
{
    ans <- readline(prompt="Do you want to go back to the Probability Analysis Menu ?(y/n)\n")

    if(ans == 'y' | ans == 'n')
        break
    else
        cat("Wrong Input. Enter again.\n")
}

if(ans == 'y')
    ProbAnl()
else
    Comb()

}
```

Comment: Can you show the minimal reproducible code that still has the issue, instead of dumping all of it? Not executing is quite vague. I guess you need to `cat` or `print` that `sprintf` part.

Comment: Ok yes, use e.g. `cat(sprintf("C(n,r): %.10f", comb), '\n')`, or just `cat('C(n,r): ', comb, '\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function

```
as.integer(readline(prompt="Set size(n): "))
```

returns a NA

because as.integer("1") returns NA

Try using :

```
as.integer(as.numeric(readline(prompt="Set size(n): "))
```

Note : to see what happens in your function, you can type *debug(Comb)*
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/debug.html
 that way you can test what is happening in your function's environment. I hope this solves your problem.